# How can we get details from twitter and facebook using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

How can we get details from twitter and face book using PHP
suppose think that i am developing a site which have Twitter and Face book Log in, i will have only a user name not so much details,that's why i am asking, how can i get details like,
DOB,Address,Current Town, Country So on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's about starting to go over their API docs?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation

Comment: Is twitter giving us the details like DOB,Town so on?

Comment: @Alex see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404956/how-can-we-get-details-from-twitter-and-facebook-using-php/3404966#3404966)

Comment: @Gordon What this that Link means?

Comment: @Alex - all the info can be easily found in the API docs. I suggest you take the time to go over them.